# How to cast array data from object to float64 after reading an Excel file with Pandas/NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, lmfit

I am trying to import a number of Excel files in a for loop and cast a column from the file as an array of type `float64`, to be used later in an lmfit function. To do so, I read the Excel files (iterated by an index), put data from one column into a list, and then cast the list as an array. Shown below:

```
isolated_peak_df = pd.read_excel(path + r'/Residuals_{}.xlsx'.format(i), header=None)
isolated_peak = [a for a in isolated_peak_df.transpose().iloc[0].loc[0:50]]
isolated_340_peak = np.array(isolated_340_peak)
```

This works for other purposes, but when I attempt to use the newly-created array to do some math in an lmfit function, I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64')
> according to the rule 'safe'

I've seen a number of questions (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449101/cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypeo-to-dtypefloat64-according-to-the-rule), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452792/cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypeo-to-dtypefloat64), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652764/typeerror-cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypeo-to-dtypefloat64-according)) asking for workarounds to the same error, but none of them resolve this specific situation, and trying to use advice in the answers continues to lead to errors. For example,

- I tried to add `dtype='float64'` as an argument to the `np.array()` call, like how Adrine Correya suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974538/13430381), but the same error remained.
- I tried adding `isolated_peak_df = isolated_peak_df.astype('float')` the line after I defined isolated_peak_df, and I also tried adding `pd.to_numeric(isolated_peak)` in both the line after I defined isolated_peak as a list and in the line after I defined isolated_peak as an array, as Nick suggested in the comments below. However, in all cases, the same error remained.
- Additionally, as MHO suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161412/13430381), I made sure that the sizes of the array shown above matches the size of the array with which mathematical operations are being performed (and I also did a basic subtraction by making an `np.zeros()` array with the same size to verify that the issue was with the newly created array above, and not the latter).
- And, as xagg suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75890729/13430381) and hpaulj advised in the comments below, I made sure that all of the values passed were indeed floating-point numbers, not strings or other non-numeric data.

Other answers provided were specific to scipy/sci-kit and not lmfit. What is going wrong?

---

**Edit:** I now suspect that the error is less to do with the data type of the array, as the error would imply, but in the size of the parameters I am using in the lmfit function. By decreasing the starting value of the "x" and "y" parameters by several orders of magnitude (e.g., down to 5), the error no longer appears...

```
freeParams = Parameters()
freeParams.add("x", value = 5 * (10 ** 20), vary=True)
freeParams.add("y", value = 5 * (10 ** 15), vary=True)
```

To my knowledge, this shouldn't cause an issue because float64 can store decimal numbers ranging between 2.2E-308 to 1.7E+308. So I'm not sure why 5e15 or 5e20 would induce an error. The rest of the code is shown below:

```
epsfcn=0.01
ftol=1.e-10
xtol=1.e-10
max_nfev=300

for i in absorption.index:
    isolated_peak_df = pd.read_excel(path + r'/Residuals_{}.xlsx'.format(i), header=None)
    isolated_peak = [a for a in isolated_peak_df.transpose().iloc[0].loc[0:50]]
    isolated_peak = np.array(isolated_peak)
    
    def calc_residual(freeParams, isolated_peak):
        residual = isolated_peak[5:22] - np.zeros(17)
        return residual

    mini = minimize(calc_residual, freeParams, args=(isolated_peak,), epsfcn=epsfcn, ftol=ftol, xtol=xtol, max_nfev=max_nfev, calc_covar=True, nan_policy="omit")
```

Note that "x" and "y" aren't used in the above code only because I wanted to test out what was going wrong, and so I chose to do a simple subtraction operation that should have given a result (in `residual`) equal to the originally imported array (`isolated_peak`) -- ultimately, however, I will need to incorporate both parameters, "x" and "y."

---

Edit: Full error message, per hpaulj's request:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[202], line 19
     16     residual = isolated_peak[5:22] - np.zeros(17)
     17     return residual
---> 19 mini = minimize(calc_residual, freeParams, args=(isolated_peak,), epsfcn=epsfcn, ftol=ftol, xtol=xtol, max_nfev=max_nfev, calc_covar=True, nan_policy="omit")

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py:2600, in minimize(fcn, params, method, args, kws, iter_cb, scale_covar, nan_policy, reduce_fcn, calc_covar, max_nfev, **fit_kws)
   2460 """Perform the minimization of the objective function.
   2461 
   2462 The minimize function takes an objective function to be minimized,
   (...)
   2594 
   2595 """
   2596 fitter = Minimizer(fcn, params, fcn_args=args, fcn_kws=kws,
   2597                    iter_cb=iter_cb, scale_covar=scale_covar,
   2598                    nan_policy=nan_policy, reduce_fcn=reduce_fcn,
   2599                    calc_covar=calc_covar, max_nfev=max_nfev, **fit_kws)
-> 2600 return fitter.minimize(method=method)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py:2369, in Minimizer.minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
   2366         if (key.lower().startswith(user_method) or
   2367                 val.lower().startswith(user_method)):
   2368             kwargs['method'] = val
-> 2369 return function(**kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py:1693, in Minimizer.leastsq(self, params, max_nfev, **kws)
   1691 result.call_kws = lskws
   1692 try:
-> 1693     lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
   1694 except AbortFitException:
   1695     pass

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:426, in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    424     if maxfev == 0:
    425         maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
--> 426     retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
    427                              gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    428 else:
    429     if col_deriv:

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: Have you tried `.astype('float')` and `pd.to_numeric`? What results did  you get from them?

Comment: Tried both, same error. Going to add the lmfit part of the code to the question as maybe that has some relevance? I noticed that when I changed the starting values of "x" and "y", the error disappeared... I'm now beginning to wonder if maybe the error is with how large the variables are.

Comment: see what [`.can_cast()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html) returns for some of the values .. you may find `.astype("float64", casting="unsafe")` works, but the results are likely to be erroneous

Comment: Is the 'cant cast' error always in the `lmfit` call?  Do the `np.array` calls with dtype or `astype` work?  Descriptions of alternatives that you try are fine, but often we need to see the actual error with full traceback.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry about that - the complete error message is now included.

Comment: So make sure `calc_residual` returns a numeric result when given sample data.

Comment: I assume this is package documentation that you are following, https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html

Comment: Yes, that's the documentation I'm following -- and calc_residual is definitely returning an array of numeric data, after all the code above is just numbers being subtracted by zero.

Comment: @hpaulj When I add a print statement for the variable `residual` just before the return statement in the above code, all of the values are indeed numeric: https://i.imgur.com/rTxC3wt.png

Answer (score 0):

With the example code from `scipy.leastsq`:

```
In [122]: from scipy.optimize import leastsq
     ...: def func(x):
     ...:     return 2*(x-3)**2+1
     ...: leastsq(func, 0)
Out[122]: (array([2.99999999]), 1)
```

providing a numeric array:

```
In [124]: leastsq(func, np.array([1,2,3]))
Out[124]: (array([1., 2., 3.]), 2)
```

But if I make it an object dtype array, I get an error that's a lot like your `lmfit` one:

```
In [125]: leastsq(func, np.array([1,2,3]).astype(object))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[125], line 1
----> 1 leastsq(func, np.array([1,2,3]).astype(object))

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:426, in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    424     if maxfev == 0:
    425         maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
--> 426     retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
    427                              gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    428 else:
    429     if col_deriv:

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

The print of an object dtype array may look the same as the numeric dtype, but the fuller `repr` display shows the dtype

```
In [127]: print(np.array([1,2,3]).astype(object))
[1 2 3]

In [128]: np.array([1,2,3]).astype(object)
Out[128]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
```